# SQL IN equivalent in DynamoDb in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been given a task to return the data for a list of items whose ids I have. The table has an id defined as:
...

```
"KeySchema" [ 
    0: { 
        "AttributeName":"id"
        "KeyType":"HASH"
        "TableStatus":"ACTIVE"
```

I have a list of say 100 of these ids and want to query to return the details in a similar way to how IN works in SQL.

I have tried many approaches but cant see a way I can make a single query to the DynamoDB instance where it will return all documents for the Ids in a supplied list.

I hope to use DynamoDBMapper.

I thought I'd hit the jackpot when I found `withHashKeyValues` on `DynamoDBQueryExpression`.

e.g.

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyObject> ddqe;
...
for (String idStr : idList) {
        MyObject mo= new MyObject();
        mo.setId(idStr);

        ddqe.withHashKeyValues(mo);
    }
```

but looking at the code although the method is plural there is a note that says:

```
Note 1: Currently the DynamoDBMapper supports only one value per hash key.
```

I have also tried a Condition (amongst many other things)

```
    Condition condition = new Condition();
    condition.withAttributeValueList(filters);
    condition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ);
```

Where filters is an ArrayList of the ids.

Is there a way to do this in DynamoDb or have I got to query the DB for every known id individually, e.g. issue 100 query's to the data store?

Answer (score 1):

Queries start at a particular Partition key, so you would have to look up one key at a time with the Query API. Instead, you could use the [BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) API and request 25 items a time.